# How to replace the MATLAB functions table and table2array in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to run my MATLAB script in Octave but have problems with the `table` function which does not yet exist in Octave.

An extract of the table that I want to work with looks as follows:

```
Rotation angle  Measured distance
-0,342  0,000
-1,440  0,000
-10,422 0,000
-11,574 0,000
-21,060 0,000
-21,528 0,000
-30,402 0,000
```

To create my output variable I am using the following code in MATLAB.

```
data = table;
data.Rotationangle = cell2mat(raw(:, 1));
data.Measureddistance = cell2mat(raw(:, 2));
```

In Octave I get the following error then.

```
warning: the 'table' function is not yet implemented in Octave

Please read <https://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
error: 'table' undefined near line 102 column 8
error: called from
    Cloud_reconstruction at line 102 column 6
```

My question is now, is there any opportunity to replace the table function in Octave? I tried to find a solution with Octave `data frame` package but was not really able to.

In the same script I am also using the `table2array` function which is also not yet implemented in Octave and will later occur an error as well.

```
data = table2array(data);
```

I would be glad if someone could help me with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use similar syntax for "column" indexing with a struct

```
data = struct;
data.var1 = [1;2;3;4];
data.var2 = [5;6;7;8];
```

However, you lose a lot of the table-specific operations available in MATLAB.

If you've got the above data, you can use `struct2array` instead of `table2array` for your conversion to a matrix

```
data = struct2array( data );
```

If you are using `table2array` anyway, you'll end up with a matrix, so why not just stick to matrices in the first place? If all of your data is numeric, they will be generally faster to operate on.

```
data = [cell2mat(raw(:,1)), cell2mat(raw(:,2))];
```

---

Edit: it appears `struct2array` may also be [missing](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50622) from Octave. However, in that missing link you can find several attachments for equivalent functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your help I was able to replace the functions. Unfortunately another error occurs now concerning a 'dimension mismatch' which I am not able to solve by myself.. I guess I have to post a new question for that? I just ask because I am new to Stack Overflow and do not know exactly how it is handled here.

Comment: Glad I could help, yep that sounds like a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

I invite you to try my Tablicious package, which provides a Matlab-compatible Octave implementation of `table`, `datetime`, and related classes.

https://github.com/apjanke/octave-tablicious

Comment: Link-only answers are usually better suited as comments under the question. This could be improved by showing how the package could actually be used in the context of this question.